# unable to access controller functions in command line or console application

Tags: doctrine-orm, console-application, symfony-2.6

I am preparing a console application and making a connection to database using container of entity manager. This works fine. Code is below

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    // get Doctrine
    $this->em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    // find all disc that are not treated by Manager in last week i.e sysdate - 6
    $pendingApprovals = $this->em->getRepository('GMRestBundle:TDtlsDisc')->getPendingManagerAppoval();
    // for each unapproved disc, start sending emails

    $repository = $this->em->getRepository('GMRestBundle:TDtlsDisc');
    $emailReminder = new SubmitDisclosureController();      
    foreach($pendingApprovals as $labManagerReview) {           
        $tDtlsDiscEntity = $repository->findByDiscId($labManagerReview['DISC_ID']);
        $emailReminder->sendMailToLabManager($tDtlsDiscEntity);
    }
}
```

Now, the issue is it is giving error when I call thsi `$emailReminder->sendMailToLabManager($tDtlsDiscEntity);` which will in turn makes a connection of orm and get some data from database. This `sendMailToLabManager` is in `SubmitDisclosureController` and the code is below.

```
public function sendMailToLabManager($tDtlsDiscEntity)
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('GMRestBundle:TXrefDiscSso');
    $entityRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('GMRestBundle:TDtlsEntity');
    $discId = $tDtlsDiscEntity->getDiscId();
.......
```

In console application, I am no able to use any controller which access DB by making another connection to doctrine object. Same controller if I called through another action controller in web, it works well.

```
 Error: Call to a member function has() on null
```

I see this above error message now.

Comment: $emailReminder->setContainer($this->getContainer()) will get you past the error message but you should not be calling controller methods directly.  Make your EmailReminder a stand alone service and then share it with both the command and the controller: http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html Understanding services is a critical part of using the Symfony framework effectively.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a service which provides the function instead of using the controller. After that you have to insert the `EntityManager` via dependency injection in to the the service.

If your command `extends ContainerAwareCommand` you can use `$this->get()` inside your command to retrieve the service you have defined before.